# How can I access all properties of an object by clicking the Image property from that object

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a music player for a project and I'm trying to add an onclick function to play the individual songs when the song image is clicked.

In order to do this, I need to click the image and get access to the song file to then store that file in state which can the be passed to my music player.

I want to know how can I access all properties of an object by clicking an image from that object?

```js
const songs = [
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon, // This will be the image that's going to be clicked
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro // This is what I need access to for my state
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const songs = [
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon,
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro
  },
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon,
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro
  },
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon,
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro
  }
]
const handleClick = (index) => () => {
  var song = songs[index];
  // you can use song object here
  // Add your code
}
render(
<div>
  {songs.map((item, index) => {
    <div key={index} onClick={handleClick(index)}>
      <img src="your/image/path" />
    </div>
  })}
</div>
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I'm not sure what you mean by // you can use song object here
  // Add your code . Can you elaborate on what's needed here? thanks

Comment: You said "I want to know how can I access all properties of an object by clicking an image from that object?"

You can access any property of the object like

"song.poster"

Answer (score 0):

```
 export default function SampleComponent() {

  const songs = [
    {
      artist: "Kings of Leon",
      songName: "Pyro",
      poster: KingsOfLeon, // This will be the image that's going to be clicked
      songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro // This is what I need access to for my state
    }
  ];
  const handleClick = (song)=>{
    //Here song is your desired object that contain all property of the clicked song 
    //you can store this song in any state like setState(song)
    //you can access all property of clicked song here like song.songFile
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {songs.map((song) => {
        <div key={song.id} onClick={()=>handleClick(song)}>
          <img src=`${song.poster}`/>
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```